# iPad:the server requires a client certificate

Tags: ipad, firefox, ssl, https, mobile-safari

I have https server configured with ssl options.I configured certificates in Settings>General>Profiles.

When I access my server using Safari browser it works fine. But same doesn't work with Firefox,chrome and my ios app.

Do I need to do any specific step to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible to solve this issue :/

I'm having the exact same problem: I have installed a custom certificate on my IPad and the secure connection works fine on Safari, but on Firefox the website tells me that there is no certificate installed

On the desktop application there is an option to add certificates to Firefox (tools > security > certificates), but this option does not exists in Firefox

From my understanding this is due to Firefox for IOS having only very limited functionalities (no module for example), so unfortunately it looks like it is not possible to set Firefox for IOS to use local security certificates...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We are not a discussion forum but question and answer. Please ensure any answers you post provide a solution to the question asked.